# How to use REST with the search service?

Tags: jquery, spservices, rest, ajax, soap

I am currently using SP2010 and spservices to make SOAP requests for search. I am doing this client sided using javascript/jquery . But now I want to use REST and still on client side. This is my SOAP version in javascript:

```
var queryText;
queryText = "<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'>";
queryText += "<Query>";
queryText += "<Context>";
queryText += "<QueryText language='en-US' type='MSSQLFT'>";
queryText += "SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path FROM Scope() WHERE CONTAINS ('" + text.replace(/ /g, "+") + "') AND ((\"SCOPE\" = '" + scope + "')) ORDER BY \"Rank\" DESC";
queryText += "</QueryText>";
queryText += "</Context>";
queryText += "<Range><Count>" + searchLimit + "</Count></Range>";

queryText += "<TrimDuplicates>false</TrimDuplicates>";
queryText += "<IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>false</IgnoreAllNoiseQuery>";
queryText += "<IncludeSpecialTermResults>true</IncludeSpecialTermResults>";
queryText += "<IncludeRelevantResults>true</IncludeRelevantResults>";
queryText += "<IncludeHighConfidenceResults>true</IncludeHighConfidenceResults>";

queryText += "</Query>";
queryText += "</QueryPacket>";
```

Can anyone please show my how to do this same thing in REST?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no REST search service in 2010. Only listdata.svc for lists and ExcelRest.aspx for excel services.

Comment: What about this: http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2011/08/31/sharepoint-2010-search-via-rest.aspx (however this is c#)

Comment: Didn't realized you were talking about creating a service. Yes, you can create a restful web service to implement SharePoint search. I did something similar with the Exchange Web Service to push SharePoint calendar events to people's Outlook calendars